# Why is my javascript requiring 2 clicks instead of 1?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the following `JS` code to play an `HTML5` custom video and - at the same time - activating an `iframe`, that will be launched just 27 seconds after the play video button is clicked.

But, I'm experiencing 2 issues:

1. The play button is requiring 2 clicks to start the video, instead of
   just 1
2. The iframe is randomly activated even when the play video button
   isn't clicked (between 25 and 40 seconds after the page is loaded,
   randomly)

Any idea why?

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">window.onclick=function() {
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("dwayne").style.display="block"',27000);
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("blackrussian").style.display="inline"',27000);
    var video=document.getElementById("167868028");
    var playButton=document.getElementById("play-pause");
    playButton.addEventListener("click",function(){if(video.paused==true){video.play();
    playButton.innerHTML="&nbsp;";}else{video.pause();
    playButton.innerHTML="&nbsp;";}});
    }</script>
```

Here's the html part:

```html
    <video class="video-js" id="167868028" preload="false" width="910" height="510" poster="img/snapshot.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="video/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
    <div class="controls"><button type="button" id="play-pause" class="play"><img src="img/play.png"></button></div>
    <iframe id="dwayne" class="whiterussian" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" src="files/iframe.php"></iframe>
    <div id="blackrussian"></div>
```

Comment: html code please

Comment: I did answer this before but you seemed to have problems yet didn't answer a question a question nor highlight what was wrong.

Comment: @RamRaider I didn't have enough knowledge to follow-up your tips, so I had to give up and try it by myself using a working code, and just smally editing it.

Comment: You are using 2 click events, first one activate the second. Try replacing `window.onclick` by `window.onload`, should works. Try also replacing `"click"` by `"mousedown"` or `"mouseup"` or `"touchstart"` etc. Search for js event types.

Comment: Nope, with window onload the iframe gets activated with timer, with current setting. I just probably have to follow what Still_learning user says... I just don't have knowledge to correctly edit the code myself :")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the playButton.addEventListener nested inside the window.onclick, could be that's what's causing the two-click requirement.

And the setTimeout is inside window.click but not inside playButton.addEventListener("click"..., meaning clicking the button will not fire it, but clicking the window will, (after 27 seconds).

```
window.onload=function() {

    var video=document.getElementById("167868028");
    var playButton=document.getElementById("play-pause");
    playButton.addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        setTimeout('document.getElementById("dwayne").style.display="block"',27000);
        setTimeout('document.getElementById("blackrussian").style.display="inline"',27000);

        if(video.paused==true){
            video.play();
            playButton.innerHTML="&nbsp;";
        }else{
            video.pause();
            playButton.innerHTML="&nbsp;";
        }
    });
}
```

Haven't tested the code but it should work...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query, here the simplest way to make it works.

When clicking one time anywhere on the page, the video will start. Then 27 seconds later, the iframe receive a new `src` url, and then load.

```js
window.onclick=function() {
    document.getElementById("167868028").play()
    setTimeout(loadFrame, 27000)
}

function loadFrame(){
  document.getElementById("dwayne").src = "http://arunranga.com/examples/access-control/"
}
```

```html
<video id="167868028" width="91" height="51" poster="img/snapshot.jpg">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<iframe id="dwayne" frameborder="3" src="" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```